# How to add another value in gauge chart js

Tags: javascript, css

[images gauge chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqI1P.png).png

I have these 2 images [images gauge chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqI1P.png).png the first one is created with gauge. I'm struggling to add the red line and the value from the second image dynamically as another chart variable. All the data in the chart will be dynamic. I am using from mysql and laravel as a backend. Could you please help me. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" 
            src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<style>
        .gauge {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 250px;
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 32px;
        color: #004033;
        }

        .gauge__body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 50%;
        background: #d1dbda;
        position: relative;
        border-top-left-radius: 100% 200%;
        border-top-right-radius: 100% 200%;
        overflow: hidden;
        }

        .gauge__fill {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        width: inherit;
        height: 100%;
        background: #235b4e;
        transform-origin: center top;
        transform: rotate(0.25turn);
        transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;

        }
        .gauge__cover {
        width: 75%;
        height: 150%;
        background: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding-bottom: 25%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
      
        .chart-info1{
            float: left;
            font-size: 10px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
        .chart-info2{
            float: right;
            font-size: 10px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

 </style>
    
  </head>

  <body>
   
    <div class="gauge">
      
        <div class="gauge__body">  
          <div class="gauge__fill"></div>
          <div class="gauge__redLine"></div>
          <div class="gauge__cover"></div>
         
        </div>
         
            <span class="chart-info1" >0.0</span>
            <span class="chart-info2" >2.8.</span>
       
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const gaugeElement = document.querySelector(".gauge");

        function setGaugeValue(gauge, value) {
        if (value < 0 || value > 1) {
            return;
        }

        gauge.querySelector(".gauge__fill").style.transform = `rotate(${
            value / 2
        }turn)`;
 
  
        gauge.querySelector(".gauge__cover").textContent = `${("2.2"
        )}`;
        }
        setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, 0.8);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```